# Why is my Rubik font rendering as sans-serif (I know Rubik is essentially a child of sans-serif)?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce, fonts

This is for an a transactional email. When I view it in my inbox, the "what font" browser extension shows me the font is sans-serif.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IwyK.png)

```html
<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap');
        * {
            font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<div cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" valign="center">
    <div align="center" valign="middle">
        <a href="https://www.cedarcide.com" ><img src="https://www.cedarcide.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/CC-Text-Logo_10Grey-copy.png" width="250" height="80" style=" margin: 0; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px; " alt="Cedarcide" ></a>
    </div>
    <div width="600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="devicewidth" style="background-color: #F9F7F0; border-radius: 50px; max-width: 600px">
        <div width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="center" style="background-color: #D9E1D6; border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0; height: 120px;">
            <div style="height: 1px"></div>
            <h2 style="color: #1D4721; font-size: 42px;">Your Order Has Shipped!</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? is Rubik installed on your machine?

Comment: Chrome, if I am importing the font from Google's api I shouldn't have to download the font to my local machine. At least this is how I have done it on projects in the past. I need my customers to also be able to view the rubik font so downloading on my local machine is not a viable option. These are automated transactional emails with shipstation.